# My App was suspended in background state by iOS when there is an active VoIP Call

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

I develop a VoIP call application. The problematic scenario is like below

- App is in background state and the device is locked
- App receives a    VoIP Push for an incoming call
- App reports an incomingCall to the    CallKit and I start a
  background task for 10 seconds
- User answers the    call
- Call is established and I end the background task (so it was active for just 10 secs)
- After 13 secs of incoming call received, iOS suspends my app and
  the call ends.

So, I would expect iOS to not suspend my app when there is an active CallKit call.
What would be wrong here, What would you suggest?

Here are what background modes I use in the app
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help in advance.

Comment: Why do you have to create background task? The delegate handled from the PushKit can just invoke the call kit to make the call reference : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit

Comment: I already invoke CallKit to report that incoming call once the VoIP push is received. I start the background task after reporting that call to the CallKit in order to have some more execution time especially when app is in background state.

Comment: What prevents you from making foreground task?

Comment: @Erhan As per the doc `PushKit provides an efficient way to manage calls that doesn’t require your app to be running to receive calls` So I believe even when the app is in background its managed by PushKit so need to invoke a BG thread, can you try that approach and see if it works for you?